# Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent

Tags: pluggable, warnings

I've just received this error/warning after trying to upload an image, any ideas what it means and what I can do to fix it?

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/achenn/public_html/wp-content/themes/whskytngfxtrt/functions.php:14) in /home/achenn/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 866

[Here's my site, live.](http://whskytngfxtrt.com)

functions.php:

```
<?php

// sidebar functions

if(function_exists('register_sidebar'))
{
    register_sidebar();
}


?>


<?php

// portfolio functions

    add_action('init', 'create_portfolio');
    function create_portfolio() {
        $portfolio_args = array(
            'label' => __('Portfolio'),
            'singular_label' => __('Portfolio'),
            'public' => true,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'capability_type' => 'post',
            'hierarchical' => false,
            'rewrite' => true,
            'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail')
        );
        register_post_type('portfolio',$portfolio_args);
    }
?>

<?php

// custom input- portfolio backend

    add_action("admin_init", "add_portfolio");
    add_action('save_post', 'update_website_url');
    function add_portfolio(){
        add_meta_box("portfolio_details", "Portfolio Options", "portfolio_options", "portfolio", "normal", "low");
    }
    function portfolio_options(){
        global $post;
        $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
        $website_url = $custom["website_url"][0];
?>
    <div id="portfolio-options">
        <label>Website URL:</label><input name="website_url" value="<?php echo $website_url; ?>" />     
    </div><!--end portfolio-options-->   
<?php
    }
    function update_website_url(){
        global $post;
        update_post_meta($post->ID, "website_url", $_POST["website_url"]);
    }
?>

<?php 

// detail columns- portfolio backend

add_filter("manage_edit-portfolio_columns", "portfolio_edit_columns");
add_action("manage_posts_custom_column",  "portfolio_columns_display");

function portfolio_edit_columns($portfolio_columns){
    $portfolio_columns = array(
        "cb" => "<input type=\"checkbox\" />",
        "title" => "Project Title",
        "description" => "Description",
    );
    return $portfolio_columns;
}

function portfolio_columns_display($portfolio_columns){
    switch ($portfolio_columns)
    {
        case "description":
            the_excerpt();
            break;              
    }
}
?>
```

portfolio.php-

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Portfolio
*/
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
    <div id="content">
    <?php 
        $loop = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'portfolio', 'posts_per_page' => 10)); 
    ?>
    <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
    <?php   
        $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
        $screenshot_url = $custom["screenshot_url"][0];
        $website_url = $custom["website_url"][0];
    ?>
        <div id="portfolio-item">
        <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        <a href="<?=$website_url?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?> </a>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>  
        </div><!-- #content -->
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Did you read [these answers](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Cannot+modify+header+information%22)?

Comment: We need to know what's in your `functions.php` file to debug that. But the `pluggable.php` error is occuring when WP tries to redirect you somewhere else ... so something is happening on your site, but without seeing your code, we can't help!

Comment: just added! sorry for leaving it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the looks of things, some page is trying to load your `functions.php` page directly.  I'm not sure if it's another part of your theme, or a plugin, or some other custom code.  But the error on line 14 is triggered with a second `<?php` opening tag in your `functions.php` file.

This `headers already sent` error is triggered when you send any additional whitespace, line returns, or text when you're not supposed to.  A short-term fix is to remove the extra markup:

```
<?php // sidebar functions
if(function_exists('register_sidebar')) {
    register_sidebar();
}

// portfolio functions
add_action('init', 'create_portfolio');
```

See how much more compact that is?  No extra white space between `?>` and `<?php` either.

For the long-term, though, you need to narrow down exactly what you're doing.  Where are you uploading the image from?  Why is it trying to redirect to your `functions.php` file?  Answer those questions and fix whatever problems are causing the issues for a more durable fix.

Comment: I've taken care of the white space now, thank you for that suggestion. When attempting to go to my portfolio page now, I'm greeted with this-  
Fatal error: Call to undefined function the_post_thumbnail() in /home/achenn/public_html/wp-content/themes/whskytngfxtrt/portfolio.php on line 19

Any ideas?

Comment: That will be a separate question, but I'd need to see the code of your `portfolio.php` file ... it's obviously trying to call WP functions in a way that's breaking.

Comment: portfolio.php added above.  thank you for your help.. i plan on launching my site tomorrow, but it seems my limited beginners knowledge is throwing up roadblocks left and right.

Comment: You need to tell WordPress your site supports thumbnails first.  Add `add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');` to your `functions.php` file => http://nabtron.com/solved-fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-the_post_thumbnail-in/3988/

Comment: So, one other thing I've realized I need to figure out- how do I display a thumbnail image on the main portfolio page and an enlarged version with a description once clicked on?

Comment: Once again, that's an entirely separate issue.  Please accept an answer on this question and ask a new question to deal with further issues.

Comment: accepted, and thank you.

http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/46949/setting-up-portfolio-functions